# Update lines of a file based on matches from another file

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to use the 2nd columns of a refrence `ref` file as match criteria and change the first column of another `main` file for the lines matching the keyword. Updated file to be written to `out`. Below is an example. My shell script is not working. I appreciate your help.

**ref**

```
PSHELL       216  136738 
PSHELL       217  136738 
PSHELL      1786   13571 
PSHELL      1605  136513
```

**main**

```
PSHELL       216  136738 
PSHELL       218  136738 
PSHELL      1786   13571 
PSHELL      1610  136513
PSHELL      1612  136513
```

**out**

```
+PSHELL       216  136738 
PSHELL       218  136738 
+PSHELL      1786   13571 
PSHELL      1610  136513
PSHELL      1612  136513
```

**my code**

```
awk '
  FNR == NR {                         # if record from 1st file
    item[++n] = $2                    # store in indexed item array
    next                              # skip to next record
  }
  { main[++m] = $0 }                  # for 2nd file, store record in main
  END {                               # after all records processed
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)              # loop over all items
      for(j=1; j<=m; j++) {           # loop over each record in main
        line = main[j]                # save record in line
        if (j == 2)                   # if 2nd record in main
          [$2]=+[$2]
        print line >> item[i]         # append line to item file 
      }
  }
' ref main > out
```

**Error**
line 11: Syntax error

Comment: What is `[$2]=+[$2]` supposed to do?

Comment: Your example `main` file does not contain several lines with the same second field that would also be in `ref`. Please edit your question and either state that it cannot happen or add a line `PSHELL       216  foobar` to `main`, and show what output you expect in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[$2]=+[$2]` is not valid `awk` syntax. And in this case there is no reason to wait after the parsing of the second file (`main`) to print the outputs in an `END` block. You can print on the fly while parsing `main`. Anyway, for this kind of processing you should probably use an associative array instead of an indexed array, and the `in` operator to test if an element is a key of `item`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {item[$2]; next} $2 in item {printf("+")} 1' ref main > out
```

Variant: you can also conditionally modify `$0`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {item[$2]; next} {$0=($2 in item?"+":"")$0; print}' ref main > out
```